# Cognito setDeviceStatusRemembered

Tags: angular, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to set up a remember me checkbox using Cognito below is what I am using currently but when I do this it gives out the error:

MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'DeviceKey' in params

I am unsure what I am doing wrong this also happens on getDevice I tried this thinking it would give me the device key but I get the same error.

```
rememberDevice(callback: CognitoCallback){
    let cognitoUser = this.getCurrentUser();

    if (cognitoUser != null) {

        cognitoUser.getSession(function (err, session) {


            cognitoUser.setDeviceStatusRemembered({
                onSuccess: function (result) {
                    callback.cognitoCallback('Device Saved',result);
                },
                onFailure: function(err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });

        });

    }
    else{
        callback.cognitoCallback('Session Error','User not valid');
    }


}
```

I can log in fine if I leave the checkbox unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was the cognitoUser did not have a deivceKey value. first I added that manually to see it working then you can get the actual value from the access token